# How to loop through a text file (running a command) in batches of 500

Tags: powershell

I have a very large exported list in text and I need to go through each of the entries and run a command using the entry. But I wish to do this in batches of 500 - as I need to allow processing time.

What I do not understand is how I loop through the text file but only run a limited number at a time, then wait for a certain time, before running the next block until they are all completed.

Can someone help with an example which I can then apply to my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably not use a `for` loop as in @ManuelBatsching's answer since so many times in PowerShell you want to use a `ForEach-Object` or some other pipelined content.  You can still do the same basic thing, however:

```
$i = 0;
$BatchSize = 500;
$SleepSeconds = 5;

Get-Content -Path $FileName | ForEach-Object {
    $i++;

    # Do work here

    if ($i % $BatchSize -eq 0) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepSeconds;
    }
}
```

You can also do something like this and utilize the `ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content`:

```
$BatchSize = 500;
$SleepSeconds = 5;

Get-Content -Path $FileName -ReadCount $BatchSize | ForEach-Object {

    $_ | ForEach-Object {
        # Do work here
    }

    Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepSeconds;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this - it makes much more sense to me and is directly usable to my actual scenario. This as trigger to sleep "($i % $BatchSize -eq 0)"  makes much more sense to me as well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done for example with the help of the modulo operator `%`:

```
$input = 1..101
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $input.Count; $i++)
{ 
    $currentElement = $input[$i]
    if ($i % 50 -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "Sleep on element $i"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}
```

This loop will pause for 5 seconds whenever `$i` can be divided by 50 without remainder.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your quick reply! :) . The dividing by 50 is a little confusing to me especially as the total number of identities in the text file will not be an even amount. Is the idea it was start at number 1 of say 10,003 and get to 9,950 at which point this number does divide by 50 - and then pause? Before carrying on to 9,900 and pause and then 9,850 and pause etc?

Comment: You can use any modulo value that you find appropriate in your case. 50 was just an example. The total number of elements in your input doesn't matter here. You are calculating the modulo of the number of the current loop runs, not the total number of elements.